OR-Tools CP-SAT Job Shop Scheduling - grouping tasks from different jobs
I am trying to build a schedule using Google OR-TOOLS CP-SAT. I found a problem, because there is requirement, that some of the tasks from different jobs should be scheduled one after another, if they belong to the same material.
I've gathered tasks with the same material, task number and requested finish date to the same groups. As below we can see, e.g. material F task 20 group 13 is in the middle, near the end and at the end of the schedule. I'd like to keep them together.
I've tried to minimize the distance between the end and start of each task in the group, but it causes throwing some of the tasks outside the calendar and significantly extends the time to find a feasible solution.
I've also tried to understand this recipe from Laurent Perron, but I am not sure if this is the way to solve my problem.
Is there any way to force the solver to keep tasks in group, in the order that we choose before processing the data?

Is adding precedences between these tasks enough, or should they be direct successors ?
For the first case just add these precedences.
For the second case you will need a circuit constraints to do the transitive reduction from precedences to successors, then force the relevant successor arcs to be true.

They should be direct successors. Do you mean that I should add similar constraint model.Add(all_tasks[171657032 , 20].start >= all_tasks[171657031, 20]. end)?

Look at jobshop_ft06_sat.py, or the recipe you mentioned. It creates all successor arcs and links them to precedences. Do not use the ranking part, just the successor arcs.

I try to understand circuit constraint based on jobshop_ft06_distance_sat.py. Does it create a direct connection between two tasks, that will ensure that no other task will jump between them? I've spent many hours trying to achieve the queue of the tasks but I don't know what do I do wrong.  Adding a circuit should be enough? How to force arc to be true? lit = model.new_bool_var("%i follows %i" % (j2, j1)) arcs.append((j1 + 1, j2 + 1, lit)) model.add_circuit(arcs)

Yes, because each arc implies the precedence with a delay, one task cannot squeeze between two. It performs the transitive reductions from precedences to successors.
